# Missing Argument for Parameter JSONDecoder URLSession with SwiftUI MVVM

Tags: ios, json, mvvm, swiftui, combine

I'm trying to learn how to use an API with SwiftUI using Combine and MVVM. I'm super new to this so this may seem like a dumb question but I've got my WebService and it seems to check out but my ViewModel is asking for stuff that I don't know if it should.

I'd like to be able to search for a game by it's name and it pull from the API.

Here's my Game.swift Model:

```
struct Game: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}
```

Simple enough.

Here's my handy WebService: GameService.swift

```
class GameService {
    func getGames(name: String, completion: @escaping (Game?) -> ()) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api-v3.igdb.com/games/") else { return }

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.setValue("HIDDEN SO YOU CAN'T GET ME IN TROUBLE", forHTTPHeaderField: "user-key")
        request.httpBody = "fields id,name".data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print("No data in response: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown Error").")
                return
            }

            if let gameResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Game.self, from: data) {
                print("Yay")
            } else {print("Shit")}

        }.resume()
    }
}
```

I'm getting a yellow warning of Value 'gameResponse' was defined but never used... on if let gameResponse = try? JSON decoder blah blah blah.

Ok now the messy boy, I present GameViewModel.swift to you:

```
class GameViewModel: ObservableObject {

    private var gameService: GameService!

    @Published var game = Game()

    init() {
        self.gameService = GameService()
    }

    var gameName: String = ""

    func searchGames() {
        if let game = self.gameName.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed) {
            getGames(by: name)
        }
    }

    private func getGames(by name: String) {
        self.gameService.getGames(name: name) { game in
            if let game = game {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.game = game
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

BIG QUESTION: The @Published var game = Game() is saying that there are is a missing parameter 'from' in call. I haven't implemented from anywhere.

The find searchGames() function is giving me an unresolved identifier error with getGames(by: name). Any ideas?

Comment: Can you simplify your question? Please remove words that aren't contributing to the question. I read this a couple of times and still not clear what exactly the problem is that you're facing

Comment: @NewDev sure man. Sorry for the humor. Didn't mean to make this more complicated.

Comment: I don't mind the humor, but try to be as clear as possible of what you need help with and what specifically is the problem. Also would help if you removed irrelevant lines of code (i.e. the set up of the request).

Answer (score 0):

Your call to Game() in GameViewModel references a constructor that does not exist since your struct does not have any default values.

To correctly initialize game, you must call the initializer with parameters:

```
Game(id: 1, name: "fred")
```

The reference to the missing parameter "from" is due to the Codable protocol defining another constructor function:

```
init(from decoder: Decoder)
```

and XCode is using this constructor as the default and being helpful by telling you that you need to supply the missing info.

`getGames(by: name)` requires a parameter called "name" which does not appear to be defined anywhere in the example you give.

Comment: Ok so no clue where to correctly initialize that Game with Fred. Is that in the Model, the VM, or the View? Also missing from decoder error is on the @Pulished value. I updated the getGames(by: name). Still getting an unused error.

Comment: Game should be initialized either at design time or on initialization to represent an “empty” state. I still do not see where “name” is defined to be passed into the getGame(by: name) method. Should you really be using getGame(by: gameName) ? (Or getGames(by: game.name))

Comment: I made some edits. I adjusted getGames(by: name). Should I add the Game(id: 1, name: "Fred") on the init in the ContentView or in the ViewModel?

Comment: Also adding the github link

Comment: Looking at the github link from my ipad, it looks like the Game struct IS actually initialized with default values - so that can be discarded as an issue. But, there are two things that stand out: getGame(by: name) should be changed to either getGame(by: game.name) or getGame(by: gameName) - it all depends on what "self.gameName.addingPercentEncoding...." does, and the game search webservice needs to call the completion code as opposed to printing out a meaningless result...

Comment: Change getGame(by: name) to getGame(by: game).

Comment: Change print("Yay") to: completion(gameResponse)

Comment: Sweet! I'm not getting errors but it's not decoding properly. On to the next issue. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215066/discussion-between-andywalt-and-woneill1701).